# 제가 김밥을 준비할까요? 그럼 부탁해요 or 준비합시다

Tags: grammar, word-usage, spoken-korean

This question below is from my Korean textbook.

> A 제가 김밥을 준비할까요?
>
> B 네，_________________
>
> a) 그럼 부탁해요.
> b) 준비합시다.

The answer is the option a. However, I am wondering why b doesn't work here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I can't see a situation where this conversation will take place with these exact phrases and honorific conjugations, but let me take a stab at why (a) is better than (b).

Since the question is, "Shall **I**...?" it is awkward to say, "yes, let's!" and a better teaching premise to answer with a "yes, you are requested to do so [i am requesting you to do so]".

Answer (score 3):

The person offered to prepare the food, and you are simply accepting the offer. It would be weird if the conversation went:

> Should I prepare the food?
>    Yes, let's prepare the food.

Because the offer implies that you are going to do the work alone, or at least without the listener.

Comment: I think this question is not asked well. Controversies are surely to be caused.

Answer (score 3):

> 제가 김밥을 준비할까요?

라고 했으므로,

> b) (**같이**) 준비합시다!

가 아닌

> a) 그럼 부탁해요.

가 더 잘 어울립니다.
b)는 '함께 하자'는 의미이므로, "**제가** 김밥을 준비할까요?"와 어울리지 않습니다.

Answer (score 1):

> A : 제가 김밥을 준비할까요?

Shall I prepare 김밥?

> B with a) : 네, 그럼 부탁해요.

Yes, please.

> B with b) : 네, 준비합시다.

Yes, let's do that.

If I were to say `"Let's do that together."` to `"Shall I prepare 김밥?"`, I'd rather say `"우리 함께 준비합시다."` not `"네, 우리 함께 준비합시다."` **Since B already said `"네"`**, I think b) is an awkward choice.

If A asked like `"우리 같이(or 함께) 김밥 준비할까요?"`, than b) would be the answer, not a).

However, for some *rare* context b) also might make sense, such as when A actually wants to make 김밥 together with B, but if B doesn't want to be bothered with.

If I were to choose only one of them, I would choose a).